# Use "history" command to fire last run command?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian

How do I use the "history" command to fire the last run command?

Comment: the `up` arrow key does the work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wouldn't. You'd use `!!`.

Comment: Provided that `histexpand` feature is on. `set -o histexpand`  to turn it on, `set +o histexpand` to turn it off.

Answer (score 6):

As Ignacio said, use `!!`, but if you insist:

```
$(history | sed '$d' | sed -n '$p' | cut -d ' ' -f 3-)
```

Explanation:

- `$()` executes the output of the command inside
- `sed '$d'` deletes the last command, i.e. `2001 $(history | sed '$d' | sed -n '$p' | cut -d ' ' -f 3-)`
- `sed -n '$p'` prints only the last line, i.e. `2000 yourpreviouscommand`
- `cut -d ' ' -f 3-` removes the first three fields, separated by spaces, i.e. `<space>2000<space>`

I think it can be made more concise and robust, but it works for now.

**Edit**: If you want to use `history` instead of `!!` because the shell you're using doesn't have `!!`, you're out of luck; `history` is a shell built-in, not a program. And simple shells are not likely to have it if they don't have `!!`. For example, dash doesn't:

```
imgx64@home:~$ dash
$ history
dash: history: not found
$
```

Comment: Deeply evil. Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, the `fc` command may do what you're looking for.

From `man bash`:

> ...
>   In  the  second form, command is re-executed after each instance
>                 of pat is replaced by rep.  A useful alias to use with  this  is
>                 **`r="fc  -s"`**,  so  that  typing **`r cc`** runs the last command
>                 beginning with **`cc`** and typing **`r`** re-executes the last command.
>   ...